# Unable check registry with NSIS for python installation

Tags: registry, nsis

I need to check registry for make sure there is no same app with the one i want to to install,
and for my issue i want to check python windows registry installation for example

the registry i need to check as belo
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.7

i already use ReadRegStr but unable to detect
also ${registry::KeyExists}
the result it's the same
both function only got exist value when the registry change to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python"

```
${registry::KeyExists} "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.7" $0
StrCmp $0 "0" haveinstallx
goto notinstall
MessageBox MB_OK "not found"
quit
notinstall:
   MessageBox MB_OK "Not installed"
   Quit

haveinstallx:
   MessageBox MB_OK "Apps have installed"
   Quit
```

with script above the result always said "Not installed"

Help and suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any more information my only guess is a 32/64 bit mismatch. Use `SetRegView` or `ReadRegStr $x HKLM64 Software\...` when running a 32-bit installer on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Thank u.
based on ur suggestion, i put SetRegView at top of it, and then combine with EnumRegKey, 
voila .......... i able to find the key

Comment: You technically should use x64.nsh to detect 64-bit if you also care about 32-bit.